# Why do homogenous linear systems have determinant zero?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm studying eigenvalues and stumbled upon this:

The system

$(A-\lambda_i \mathbb{1}_n)\cdot X = 0$

only if

$\det(A-\lambda_i \mathbb{1}_n)=0$

I understand that this is a homogeneous linear system, and I found that they need to have determinant zero in order to have non-trivial solutions. But why exactly is this?

I'm trying to understand this intuitively instead of just taking it as it is, so any explanation is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a matrix has determinant different from 0, it is an invertible matrix. If the matrix is invertible, the system

$$Ax = b $$

Has one unique solution because one can multiply both sides by $A^{-1} $.

But we want the homogeneous system to have infinite solutions; hence the matrix cannot have determinant $\not= 0 $

Answer (score 1):

If $AX = 0$, and $\det A\neq 0$, then $A^{-1}$ is defined, so $(A^{-1}A)X = A^{-1}0$, so $X = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

> The system
>
> $(A-\lambda_i \mathbb{1}_n)\cdot X = 0$
>
> only if
>
> $\det(A-\lambda_i \mathbb{1}_n)=0$

A homogeneous system always has the zero solution $X = 0$ and for a square system ($n \times n$), this is *the only* solution if the determinant of the coefficient matrix is non-zero. So the system only has non-zero solutions $X$, the eigenvector(s), if the determinant **is** in fact $0$.